# What would be the consequences of a world where 25 years old is the age of majority?

Tags: alternate-history, politics

The human brain becomes fully developed at the age of 25 years old.

In my story, the voting age was formerly at 21 years old, after 18 years old, now it is 25 years old. Also, all drugs (ethanol, nicotine, THC, LSD, magic mushrooms, etc.) are now legal, but only at the age of 25 years old.

Comment: Traditionally questions asking "What would be the consequences of X on society?" are considered too broad for this site

Comment: VTC.  You are asking us to write the scenario for you - that's not what WB SE does.

Comment: LSD legalized ?  Seriously, do you have any idea what that stuff (and others) does to people ?  Might as well legalize murder, rape and violence in general.  Nicotine is legal so what do you think is going to change about that ?  Also "legalised" how ?  In public ?  In privatel ? In a medically and/or State controlled setting ?  In schools ?  In Hospitals ?  Are you still legally responsible for you do when drugged ?  You need to actually write a proper scenarion and on WB SE we'd comment on plausibility of *that* scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Greater sense of entitlement. If you are well out of your formative years before you could ever legally be responsible for yourself, you will be much less likely to have been trained to be responsible, much less likely to be *capable* of being responsible for yourself. If you can't/won't be responsible for yourself, you will whine/demand/insist/whine ("whine" twice for emphasis) that others be responsible for you.

Increased alcoholism and substance abuse. The trend is clear, in places where there are fewer age restrictions on the the consumption of alcohol, we see less binge drinking and/or over-compensation (assuming these aren't just aspects of the same thing).

A stronger tendency towards tyranny. It's not as if you'll be tax-exempt at age 24. You'll be paying for government you have no true representation in. As much as paternalism is a feature of tyranny, the entire concept itself is "this person can't take care of themselves, they're still a child".

Baby busts. Healthy societies/demographics should have people becoming parents (or soon to be parents) in their mid-20s. This is impossible if you're still a child. Anyone that has sex with you is, after all, a rapist. There is case law that suggests that those people are rapists even if below the age of majority themselves (even as they're simultaneously rape victims). This will discourage healthy procreation, possibly below the already unhealthy fertility rates.

Finally, it's not clear to me what people mean when they say things like "the human brain becomes fully developed only at age 25". What do they think this "development" is exactly? The human brain changes continually and constantly throughout life, even for centenarians. They aren't manufactured robots, there are no real designs that specify when a brain is "complete". The claim that brains are only fully developed at such an age is facetious or misinterpreted and has little evidence to support it.

Comment: I think the OP refers to the idea that the prefrontal cortex only fully develops by the age of 25 or so.

Comment: @Otkin That idea is a null idea... without a "design", there is no "fully develops". We might use *size* as a proxy for fullness, except that the human brain is full-sized far sooner than age 25. So we're left with a bunch of woo-woo nonsense that is circularly self-justifying.

Comment: I am not a neuroscientist, but from what I read on the subject, development refers not to the size but the development of neural structures necessary for control of one's behaviour and emotions. IIRC, maturation is connected to synaptic pruning and stabilisation of specific connections. You can google for research papers for proper and detailed explanations.  ||  Please note that I do not insist that this interpretation of the data is correct. I am just informing you about existing research.

Comment: @Otkin That's a completely circular argument. It's not as if we're talking about the brain being unconnected to the body, and little nerve ganglions in the arms and legs are controlling those things... so what we're talking about is one part of the brain controlling behavior vs. another part of the brain controlling behavior. If the brain is in control, who is to say which part should be "in control" at any given developmental stage? That one or another part of neurology should "be in control" isn't a supported argument that I can discern.

Comment: I think you need to familiarise yourself with the research. I am not an expert on this topic so I cannot provide explanations or engage in a meaningful discussion.

Comment: @Otkin The trouble is that I am familiar with it, familiar enough to understand that there's a bunch of creative interpretation going on that isn't founded in science at all.

Comment: I am not doubting your words (my previous comment meant that I am not qualified to explain the research I mentioned so it is better if you take a look yourself because I do not want to say something wrong and mislead you or anyone else). I try to avoid discussing things I have a very limited understanding of. I hope you can understand my position.